# Error using map to create Routes dinamically

Tags: arrays, reactjs, typescript, react-router

I get an error when I try to use `Route` dinamically from array.

> Warning:  is using incorrect casing. Use PascalCase for React components, or lowercase for HTML elements.

Here are the elements I'm using:

```
const steps = [
  {
    name: 'Step Name',
    description: 'Step description (can be empty)',
    link: '/',
    component: 'Welcome'
  },
  {
    name: 'Step Name 2',
    description: 'Step Description',
    link: '/step-2',
    component: 'Step2'
  }
];
```

```
<Switch>
  {steps.map((step, index) => {
    return <Route exact path={step.link} key={index} component={step.component} />;
  })}
</Switch>
```

I've tried using template literals, but I got another error:

> Overload 1 of 2, '(props: Readonly): Route', gave the following error.
>   Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'ComponentClass | FunctionComponent | ComponentClass, any> | FunctionComponent<...> | undefined'.

Comment: You are giving the `component` prop a string, not a component.

Comment: You would have to use something like `component: Welcome`, where the component is imported as `Wecome`. But just a string "Welcome" has no way to know it should be treated as a component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as @Brian said you are using strings not components while mappings. Import the component and use that instead of a string. Notice no quotes in component field's values.

```js
import Welcome from '/path/to/welcome';
import Step2 from '/path/to/step2';
const steps = [
  {
    name: 'Step Name',
    description: 'Step description (can be empty)',
    link: '/',
    component: Welcome
  },
  {
    name: 'Step Name 2',
    description: 'Step Description',
    link: '/step-2',
    component: Step2
  }
];
```